# Element using overflow: scroll has scrollbar going off screen

Tags: html, css

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding-bottom: 6em;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

The sidebar has a scroll which moves approximately 50px off the screen, please refer to image provided. I have tried using padding or margin on both body and #sidebar, to no avail.

[image: scroll going off screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have no set height on #sidebar's container, 100% height will be auto. The scrollbar will be the size of it's container (#sidebar) so it will just stretch. Try something like this:

```
#sidebar {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

You could also use window units:

```
#sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Actually the container does have a set height. Above the sidebar is the header so using top and bottom doesn't work.

Comment: So what is your desired height then, the size of the whole body? the size of the window?

Comment: Min-height doesn't constitute a set height.

Comment: I would like the sidebar to take up the rest of page height, only way I have found possible is to make the body height 100% and the sidebar 100%.

Comment: the rest of the page height below your page header? if that's the case, then if your page is long the scrollbar will often be partially hidden? or do you mean the rest of the window height? Also, do you know the height of your header?

Comment: I ended up making the header fixed and using the top and bottom like you mentioned. I had to guess the positioning from the top since the header isn't a static height. Thanks so much for your help and time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72711/discussion-between-will-reese-and-adherence).